# Why is await exiting?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Given the following code:

```
    public async Task Send() // part of Sender class
    {
          // sync code
    }

    // // 

    private async Task HandleMessage()
    {
        // await sender.Send(); // exits HandleMessage immediately
        sender.Send().Wait(); // works as expected, waiting to complete
        DoOtherStuff(); // doesn't get hit with await
        return;
    }

    RunRecurringTask(async () => await HandleMessage(), result);

    public void RunRecurringTask(Action action, RecurringTaskRunResult result)
    {
            action();
            result.DoStuff();
    }
```

I thought that `await` tells the thread to come back when the awaited thing is complete, but it looks like for some reason that's not happening: the remaining code is never hit and everything just... stops.  What could be causing this?

This is a console application in an Azure WebJob, for what it's worth.  When `Wait` is used, I get the expected results, however with `await`, the job just completes.

Comment: When `async` method find `await`, it will then delegate method execution to another thread, and method returns immediately. When method execution finished, it will comeback to execute the rest of the method.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan in my case, I want the webjob to continue running (not to report "completed") until all of the work is finished.  The behavior I'm seeing is that `DoOtherStuff` never gets logged to the webjob, unless I use `Wait`

Comment: If you are using webjobs your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916325/azure-webjobs-can-i-use-async-methods Please include the code that calls `HandleMessage`, that is likely where your problem is.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never do `async void` unless you are writing a event handler. A `Action` with the `async` modifier is a `async void` method. You need to make the argument a `Func<Task>` and then do `await action()` in your `RunRecurringTask`

```
private async Task HandleMessage()
{
    await sender.Send();
    DoOtherStuff();
    return;
}

RunRecurringTask(async () => await HandleMessage(), result);
//You also could do 
//RunRecurringTask(() => HandleMessage(), result);

public async Task RunRecurringTask(Func<Task> action, RecurringTaskRunResult result)
{
        await action();
        result.DoStuff();
}
```

If you had other methods that where not marked with `async` you will need to change all of them up the call stack till you get to the entry point from the SDK. The SDK understands how to handle functions with a `async Task` return type [since the `0.4.0-beta` version](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-0-4-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/).